# Manipulating arrays with a for loop in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop

I am trying to code a selection sort algorithm (takes a random set of ten numbers, input by user, and outputs the list in ascending order). I understand how the algorithm is supposed to work, and thought I had figured it out, but something in the for-loop isn't working the way that I was expecting and I can't for the life of me figure out what it is.

Here is an example of the problem that I am encountering:
Input {9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0}, outputs {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 9, 6, 7, 8, 9}

The fifth index always seems to be off, no matter what numbers I put in. However, if the original number set has multiples of any given number, then there will be other errors that are harder to pinpoint. I am hoping that after solving the fifth index issue, the other issues will be solved or at least easier to pinpoint.

Below is then entirety of my main function (minus the part where it actually says main).

```
int arr[10];//array of integers input by user
int num;    //smallest number in array
int temp;   //temp variable for swapping numbers
int ind;    //index of where temp was found

cout << "Enter ten random integers: " << endl;
for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
{
    cout << "[" << i << "] = ";
    cin >> arr[i];
}

cout << endl;

for (int j=0; j<10; j++)
{
    num = arr[j];
    temp = arr[j];

    for (int k=j; k<10; k++) /*after this loop, temp should have lowest int and ind
                               should have its location*/
    {
        if(temp > arr[k])
        {
            temp = arr[k];
            ind = k;
        }
    }
    arr[j] = temp;
    arr[ind] = num;
}

for(int l = 0; l<10; l++)
{
    cout << arr[l] << " ";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
temp = arr[0]; // You need to set it to sth diferent then 0

for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
{
    if(arr[k] < temp)
    {
           temp = arr[k];
           ind = k;
    }
}
```

And done.

For sorting (123):

```
  for (i = 10; i > 0; i--)
  {
    for (j = 1; j <= i; j++)
    {
      if (numbers[j-1] > numbers[j])
      {
        temp = numbers[j-1];
        numbers[j-1] = numbers[j];
        numbers[j] = temp;
      }
    }
  }
```

And reverse (321)

```
  for (i = 10; i > 0; i--)
  {
    for (j = 1; j <= i; j++)
    {
      if (numbers[j-1] < numbers[j])
      {
        temp = numbers[j-1];
        numbers[j-1] = numbers[j];
        numbers[j] = temp;
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: I was apparently trying to overcomplicate the problem. Thanks, that helped out a lot.